# AMDGPU driver apparently not loading firmware

Tags: kernel, gpu, firmware

I have an RX 580 (Polaris 10 GPU) that I am using with my Gentoo system.  I build my own kernel, which is completely typical with Gentoo.  I'm not using any initramfs, but the kernel loads the amdgpu module during the boot process.

The AMDGPU driver doesn't appear to be loading any firmware.  I've built the kernel with the following options:

```
CONFIG_DRM_AMDGPU=m
CONFIG_DRM_AMDGPU_SI=y
CONFIG_DRM_AMDGPU_CIK=y
CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE_DIR="/lib/firmware"
CONFIG_EXTRA_FIRMWARE="intel-ucode/06-2d-07 radeon/tahiti_ce.bin radeon/tahiti_mc.bin radeon/tahiti_me.bin radeon/tahiti_pfp.bin radeon/tahiti_rlc.bin radeon/tahiti_smc.bin radeon/TAHITI_uvd.bin amdgpu/polaris10_ce.bin amdgpu/polaris10_ce_2.bin amdgpu/polaris10_k_smc.bin amdgpu/polaris10_k2_smc.bin amdgpu/polaris10_k_mc.bin amdgpu/polaris10_mc.bin amdgpu/polaris10_me.bin amdgpu/polaris10_me_2.bin amdgpu/polaris10_mec2.bin amdgpu/polaris10_mec2_2.bin amdgpu/polaris10_mec.bin amdgpu/polaris10_mec_2.bin amdgpu/polaris10_pfp.bin amdgpu/polaris10_pfp_2.bin amdgpu/polaris10_rlc.bin amdgpu/polaris10_sdma1.bin amdgpu/polaris10_sdma.bin amdgpu/polaris10_smc.bin amdgpu/polaris10_smc_sk.bin amdgpu/polaris10_uvd.bin amdgpu/polaris10_vce.bin"
```

The firmware config also includes the firmware for my CPU, which loads fine, as well as my old Tahiti-based GPU.  I have verified that all the Polaris firmware specified is in the /lib/firmware/amdgpu directory, and that all the Polaris firmware in that directory is listed in the kernel config.

But I'm not seeing any messages in dmesg that either the firmware loaded, or failed to load.  [Looking around](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/304932/rx-480-amdgpu-driver-failing-to-load-on-debian-sid) I seem to find examples where firmware is supposed to have loading messages and I don't have those, e.g.:

```
[    3.603145] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/polaris10_pfp.bin
[    3.603623] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: firmware: direct-loading firmware amdgpu/polaris10_me.bin
```

But I don't have such messages, at least for the GPU.  (The CPU microcode is loading fine).

For the curious, the root of the issue is that the card has the reset bug with VFIO.  The RX 580 is known to be finicky with this, but I'm hoping that getting the updated firmware might help.  The card works well enough for displaying things in Linux, so I know basic driver functionality is fine.

'modinfo -F firmware amdgpu' produces an enormous amount of output, including all 21 firmware blobs for polaris10 and a few hundred other blobs as well, for apparently every GPU supported by the amdgpu driver.

Following is the output of "dmesg | grep -e amdgpu -e drm"

```
[    7.253557] [drm] amdgpu kernel modesetting enabled.
[    7.253688] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 0: 0xc0000000 -> 0xcfffffff
[    7.253689] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 2: 0xd0000000 -> 0xd01fffff
[    7.253690] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: remove_conflicting_pci_framebuffers: bar 5: 0xfbe00000 -> 0xfbe3ffff
[    7.253692] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: vgaarb: deactivate vga console
[    7.254864] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (POLARIS10 0x1002:0x67DF 0x1043:0x0519 0xE7).
[    7.254871] [drm] register mmio base: 0xFBE00000
[    7.254872] [drm] register mmio size: 262144
[    7.254874] [drm] PCIE atomic ops is not supported
[    7.254877] [drm] add ip block number 0 <vi_common>
[    7.254878] [drm] add ip block number 1 <gmc_v8_0>
[    7.254878] [drm] add ip block number 2 <tonga_ih>
[    7.254878] [drm] add ip block number 3 <gfx_v8_0>
[    7.254879] [drm] add ip block number 4 <sdma_v3_0>
[    7.254879] [drm] add ip block number 5 <powerplay>
[    7.254880] [drm] add ip block number 6 <dm>
[    7.254880] [drm] add ip block number 7 <uvd_v6_0>
[    7.254881] [drm] add ip block number 8 <vce_v3_0>
[    7.255067] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: No more image in the PCI ROM
[    7.255095] [drm] UVD is enabled in VM mode
[    7.255096] [drm] UVD ENC is enabled in VM mode
[    7.255097] [drm] VCE enabled in VM mode
[    7.255116] [drm] vm size is 128 GB, 2 levels, block size is 10-bit, fragment size is 9-bit
[    7.255124] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: VRAM: 8192M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F5FFFFFFFF (8192M used)
[    7.255125] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: GART: 256M 0x000000FF00000000 - 0x000000FF0FFFFFFF
[    7.255127] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=8192M, BAR=256M
[    7.255128] [drm] RAM width 256bits GDDR5
[    7.255374] [drm] amdgpu: 8192M of VRAM memory ready
[    7.255376] [drm] amdgpu: 8192M of GTT memory ready.
[    7.255391] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 65536, num gpu pages 65536
[    7.256003] [drm] PCIE GART of 256M enabled (table at 0x000000F400900000).
[    7.256064] [drm] Chained IB support enabled!
[    7.256820] amdgpu: [powerplay] hwmgr_sw_init smu backed is polaris10_smu
[    7.256827] [drm] Found UVD firmware Version: 1.130 Family ID: 16
[    7.257311] [drm] Found VCE firmware Version: 53.26 Binary ID: 3
[    7.312157] [drm] DM_PPLIB: values for Engine clock
[    7.312158] [drm] DM_PPLIB:   300000
[    7.312158] [drm] DM_PPLIB:   751000
[    7.312159] [drm] DM_PPLIB:   1048000
[    7.312159] [drm] DM_PPLIB:   1158000
[    7.312159] [drm] DM_PPLIB:   1240000
[    7.312160] [drm] DM_PPLIB:   1309000
[    7.312160] [drm] DM_PPLIB:   1364000
[    7.312160] [drm] DM_PPLIB:   1411000
[    7.312161] [drm] DM_PPLIB: Validation clocks:
[    7.312161] [drm] DM_PPLIB:    engine_max_clock: 141100
[    7.312162] [drm] DM_PPLIB:    memory_max_clock: 200000
[    7.312162] [drm] DM_PPLIB:    level           : 8
[    7.312163] [drm] DM_PPLIB: values for Memory clock
[    7.312163] [drm] DM_PPLIB:   300000
[    7.312164] [drm] DM_PPLIB:   1000000
[    7.312164] [drm] DM_PPLIB:   2000000
[    7.312164] [drm] DM_PPLIB: Validation clocks:
[    7.312165] [drm] DM_PPLIB:    engine_max_clock: 141100
[    7.312165] [drm] DM_PPLIB:    memory_max_clock: 200000
[    7.312165] [drm] DM_PPLIB:    level           : 8
[    7.312575] [drm] Display Core initialized with v3.2.35!
[    7.347039] [drm] SADs count is: -2, don't need to read it
[    7.397092] [drm] SADs count is: -2, don't need to read it
[    7.458278] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: DVI-D-1: EDID is invalid:
[    7.458288] [drm] SADs count is: -2, don't need to read it
[    7.458297] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    7.458297] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    7.484629] [drm] UVD and UVD ENC initialized successfully.
[    7.585582] [drm] VCE initialized successfully.
[    7.587422] [drm] fb mappable at 0xC0E30000
[    7.587423] [drm] vram apper at 0xC0000000
[    7.587423] [drm] size 1228800
[    7.587424] [drm] fb depth is 24
[    7.587424] [drm]    pitch is 2560
[    7.587478] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    7.634376] amdgpu 0000:01:00.0: fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
[    7.635745] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.33.0 20150101 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0
```

Comment: Silence is golden, I sea.  Did you manage to solve this by yourself?  Wondering since I'm facing the same, also with a kernel I configured myself, without initramfs.

Comment: Nope!  I eventually quit worrying about it.  I just kind of deal with the occasional balkiness when using KVM.

Comment: Is your impression that the fW is loaded or not?  I'd like to be sure, because I'm missing some functionalitye in a new laptop (touchpad not detected) when running the kernel I built.  The same kernel, built with a config copied from a distribution, has  no problem.

Comment: I honestly don't know.  I suspect it is not loaded, but I haven't experienced any problems.